# USQL ACUTE ACCENT

Tags: diacritics, u-sql, bigdata

I am new to U-SQL. I'm trying to do some basic queries and I have found a problem with how acute accents are handled.

When my data has acute accents, I get an error and I can´t continue. I'm Spanish so most of data I work with has acute accents.

Any idea? Do I need to follow some special coding protocol?

Comment: Could you please explain what problems are you experiencing?

Comment: //Read some data
@searchlog = 
    EXTRACT 
    Clave float , 
 Estudio string , 
 Turno string , 
 Fecha DateTime , 
 Plataforma string , 
 Agente string ,
 Proveedor string , 
 Servicio string , 
 Periodo float , 
 Ola string , 
 Mes string , 
 Horario string , 
 Control string , 
 Tipologia string , 
 Llamada string , 
 Rechazado string , 
 Bimestre string , 
 Supervisor string 
    FROM @"/Samples/pruebaDatosAdicionales.txt"
    USING Extractors.Text();


Ok when I insert:

//Insert it into a previously created table
INSERT INTO [Informes].[dbo].[DatosAdicionales]
SELECT *
FROM @searchlog;

Comment: And the data I am inserting have accents I get this error:

ERROR
VertexFailedFast. Vertex failure triggered quick job abort. Vertex failed: SV1_Extract_Partition[0] with error: Vertex user code error.
DESCRIPTION
Vertex failed with a fail-fast error
RESOLUTION
DETAILS

Vertex SV1_Extract_Partition[0].v1 {6DE61CE6-453A-48CB-830F-036920D864B4} failed 

Error:
Vertex user code error

exitcode=CsExitCode_StillActive Errorsnippet=An error occurred while processing ad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely running into an encoding issue.

Please check what encoding the file is in from which you are extracting (you can use notepad++ for example).

E.g., if the file is in some ANSI encoding, you will have to convert the file into UTF-8 before uploading it into the Data Lake.

The currently supported encodings are ASCII (which does not support accented characters), UTF-8 and Unicode (UTF-16) LE and BE. We are having support for ANSI code pages on our backlog. If you can provide the code page to the following uservoice item https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/13077555-add-ansi-code-page-support-for-built-in-extractors and vote, that would help us with prioritization of the backlog feature.

Comment: Olé! I changed the codification of my txt in my case, from ANSI to UTF-8 and it works properly!
Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: Great to hear! please mark my answer so other people will find it :)